# SIM800L incoming sms stuck in memory

Tags: arduino

I hit a deadened trying to receive sms on the SIM800L module with Arduino Uno.

I'm using the Receive sms sketch on the IDE, the module does not receive incoming messages and just keeps displaying one sms over and over, this message is the first one I sent to the module, and somehow it's stuck in memory. the sms.flush() method does't erase the message, how do I go about clearing memory to create space for incoming messages ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SIM800L has a vendor specific command to delete all messages, this may clear up enough space for it to receive additional messages.

1. Run `AT+CMGDA=?` to find out which mode you need to use. The modem responds with `(1-6)` or lists the responses in text mode.
2. Then run `AT+CMGDA=6` if the modem responded with numbers, or `AT+CMGDA="DEL ALL"`.

To avoid overflowing the storage, using `AT+CNMI=2,2` you can tell the modem to always forward incoming messages to the terminal and avoid storing them in the SIM card or modem memory.